# How best to keep a job queue clean of retry/duplicate jobs (using sidekiq and redis-semaphore)

Tags: ruby, redis, mutex, semaphore, sidekiq

I have a rails app that fetches a lot of emails from multiple IMAP accounts.

- I use **sidekiq** to handle the jobs.
- I use **sidetiq** to schedule the jobs.
- I use **redis-semaphore** to ensure that recurring jobs for the same user don't stumble upon each other.

2 issues though:

- 1: When a job hits "if s.lock" **redis-semaphore** puts it on hold until all previous jobs have finished. I need the job to be cancelled instead of being queued.
- 2: If during a job an exception is raised, resulting in a crash, **sidekiq** will put the job back into the queue for a retry. I need the job to be cancelled instead of being queued. Putting "sidekiq_options :retry => false" into the code does not seem to make a difference.

My code:

```
class FetchMailsJobs
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  tiq { hourly.minute_of_hour(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55) }

  def perform(last_occurrence, current_occurrence)
    users = User.all
    users.each do |user|

      if user.imap_accounts.exists?
        ImapJob.perform_async(user._id.to_s)
      end
    end
  end
end

class ImapJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(user_id)
    s = Redis::Semaphore.new("fetch_imap_mails_for_#{user_id}".to_sym, connection: "localhost")
    if s.lock
      user = User.where(_id: user_id).first
      emails = ImapMails.receive_mails(user)
      s.unlock
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### 1. Create a `Redis` subclass and overload `blpop` to accept `-1` for non-blocking use of `lpop`.

**redis-semaphore** calls `@redis.blpop` in [`Redis::Semaphore#lock`](https://github.com/dv/redis-semaphore/blob/5d05491ed2af9fba7c978bdc6e73c135aeab2ae3/lib/redis/semaphore.rb#L50).  While you could overload the `lock` method to use `@redis.lpop` instead, a much simpler approach would be to pass a custom instance of [`Redis`](https://github.com/dv/redis-semaphore/blob/5d05491ed2af9fba7c978bdc6e73c135aeab2ae3/lib/redis/semaphore.rb#L20) to the semaphore.

Place the following in the `lib` of your rails app and require it in your `config/initializers/sidekiq.rb` (or do whatever your preference might be for loading the following class).

```ruby
class NonBlockingRedis < Redis
  def blpop(key, timeout)
    if timeout == -1
      result = lpop(key)
      return result if result.nil?
      return [key, result]
    else
      super(key, timeout)
    end
  end
end
```

Whenever you call `Redis::Semaphore.new`, pass a `:redis` key with a new instance of the `NonBlockingRedis` class.

Call `s.lock` with `-1` as an argument to use `lpop` instead of `blpop`.

```ruby
s = Redis::Semaphore.new("fetch_imap_mails_for_#{user_id}".to_sym, redis: NonBlockingRedis.new(connection: "localhost"))
if s.lock -1
  user = User.where(_id: user_id).first
  emails = ImapMails.receive_mails(user)
  s.unlock
end
```

#### 2. Using `sidekiq_options retry: false` in your worker class should work, see below for an example.

In your question, you didn't specify which worker you were having problems with jobs ending up in the retry queue.  Since `FetchMailsJobs` ends up enqueing `ImapJob` jobs, an exception in the former may cause it to appear that the `ImapJob` is being re-queued.

With your semaphore lock, it would also be a good idea to wrap your work in a `begin rescue ensure` block.

```ruby
class FetchMailsJobs
  include Sidekiq::Worker
  include Sidetiq::Schedulable

  sidekiq_options retry: false

  tiq { hourly.minute_of_hour(0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55) }

  def perform(last_occurrence, current_occurrence)
    users = User.all
    users.each do |user|

      if user.imap_accounts.exists?
        ImapJob.perform_async(user._id.to_s)
      end
    end
  end
end

class ImapJob
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  sidekiq_options retry: false

  def perform(user_id)
    s = Redis::Semaphore.new("fetch_imap_mails_for_#{user_id}".to_sym, redis: NonBlockingRedis.new(connection: "localhost"))
    if s.lock - 1
      begin
        user = User.where(_id: user_id).first
        emails = ImapMails.receive_mails(user)
      rescue => e
        # ignore; do nothing
      ensure
        s.unlock
      end
    end
  end
end
```

See [sidekiq Advanced Options: workers](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq/wiki/Advanced-Options#workers) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

Would it not be possible to ditch using **redis-semaphore** and use the [sidekiq-unique-jobs gem](https://github.com/form26/sidekiq-unique-jobs) ? It seems like a nicely contained tool that does exactly what you're looking for.